# Is there a mechanism for registering module import / load hooks?

Tags: python

I'd like to register a function to be called after a Python module has been loaded. The pseudo-code I'd like to be able to write:

```
# define a module import hook
def on_module_loaded(name, origin):
  # do something in response to module called 'name' being loaded
  print(name)

# register this import hook for a module, e.g. numpy
register_import_hook(["numpy"], on_module_loaded)
```

Then, when that module is later loaded, for example by:

```
import numpy
```

the `on_module_loaded` hook would be run after the module was finished loading (assuming this is the first time `numpy` has been imported + loaded).

The [importhook](https://pypi.org/project/importhook/) module encodes one approach, which basically involves patching the module finders + loaders to invoke a registered callback when a particular module is loaded. Unfortunately, I've run into some issues where the monkey-patching done by this module causes certain modules to fail to load; e.g. the `torch` module fails to load in this case.

Is there an alternate (or, more official) approach here that doesn't involve monkey-patching the existing finders / loaders?